# Compilng hybrid program (C++&Assembler)

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, hybrid

I got a program which contains two parts, main (written in cpp) and additional (assembler). I want to compile this program using DOSBOX 0.74 and BorlandC compiler.

I've tried this:

```
bcc32 -tWC mainprogram.cpp
```

and got as a result:

> This program must be run under Win32

Why is wrong and what should I do to run this properly?

Comment: Why are you using a 20-year-old compiler and trying to run the program on an emulated 30-year-old operating system? You might have more joy with this century's tools.

Comment: What if I must do this via DOSBOX? It's an ordinance of my teacher.

Comment: Then drop the course. It won't teach you anything useful, unless you're interested in the history of ancient dialects of C++ and obsolete operating systems.

Comment: Okay, I can't argue with that. Anyway, how to make it using other tools?

Comment: bcc32 is officially a Windows compiler, so by default 'needs' Windows. Check the commandline parameters - I seem to remember OS=msdos steers the compiler to DOS.

Comment: So how many schools in your country are stubbornly and forcefully teaching how many people to use emulated DOS ffs and what can we do about it? For the sake of our industry.

Comment: Generally speaking, following the directions given in error messages, or avoiding the conditions they indicate to be a problem are a good start. Failing that, googling the exact message will provide results for the overwhelming majority of the remaining cases. Whatever the OS and IDE, research is a vital part of programming, get used to(and better at) it!

Comment: I suspect you confuse "Console" aka "DOS Prompt" and "MSDOS Environment". Please show code - especially the Assembly code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tnT5x4aB - here is assembly.

Comment: Yes, that's MSDOS assemblable with TASM with two syntax errors. Now you need a **MSDOS**-compiler. Google for "borland c++ for dos download" or "borland c for dos download" or visit [Embarcadero (Borland's successor)](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20841). Here's [a link on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096609/c-compiler-for-ms-dos).

Comment: My question was about something different. I didn't write about it, but I tried to compile it several ways, and my teacher told me that I should do it directly from the prompt using the commend on top. Are you sure that if it comes to hybrid programming, it is suitable to compile it via TASM?