# Cannot execute some DOS commands in DosBox

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

I'm trying to program batch script in dosbox, but there is no some commands.

For example, if I execute this code:

```
set var=helloworld
echo %var:~1,5%
```

I'll get empty line.

Also I can't execute `FOR` command. It says: 'Illegal command FOR'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command.com`-like command processor included with `DosBox` is not fully compatible with command syntax of MS-DOS `command.com` or especially windows NT's `cmd.exe` command processors.

See [this page](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Commands) for commands available to DosBox and their syntax. They may be similar but not the same to MS-DOS ones.

Your options are:

- use a batch file that runs outside `dosbox` for anything that does not need to be inside it
- copy and run `command.com` from a real MS-DOS or other DOS. You can get one from an image of a DOS boot floppy (or Windows 95, 98 or ME) which should be plentiful in the internet. Then refer to command-line manual for that DOS version. You will lose access to DosBox-specific commands inside it and it may try to needlessly hog the CPU as almost any other DOS program.
- write a program in any programming language that can be executed in DOS like  C ([free C compilers for DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096609/c-compiler-for-ms-dos)) and call it from DosBox. Some of the compilers are made free and available for download.